# Mat prefix shown for all mat field elements in form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a phonenumber field which has country list dropdown and input field for the user to enter phonenumber. Now once the user select the country from dropdown I'm showing the country code in input field in input field using mat prefix. Which I'm able to do successfully.

```
Myform = this.fb.group({   
    Details: this.fb.array([this.createdetails()])   
  });

createdetails(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required ]
      phone: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

switchCountryForPhoneNumber(event) {
if(event.value){ this.countrySelected = "+" + event.value.phoneCode;
}
else { this.countrySelected = '';
}
}
```

Now user can add more set of details(Name and number) by clicking add more. Now the problem I'm facing if I click on add more and select country from dropdown in row1 it is showing even in row 2. Could you guys please advice. Please refer images

[Dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqoCo.png) ; [Row1 selected but shown in row2 also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNk24.png)

```
<div
        formArrayName="Details"
        *ngFor="let item of Details.controls; let i = index"
      >
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label class="required">
              {{"Name"}}
            </mat-label>
            <input              
              formControlName="name"
              class="mat-body-1"
              matInput
            />
          </mat-form-field>          
          <div class="phn-wrapper">            
          <mat-form-field
              appearance="outline"
              class="countryCode"
              style="width: 25%"
          >
                <mat-label appearance="outline">Country</mat-label>
                <mat-select                  
                  (selectionChange)="switchCountryForPhoneNumber($event)"                   
                  #countrySelect                 
                >
                  <mat-select-trigger>
                    <span
                      [class]="
                        'flag flag-' +
                        countrySelect.value?.countryCode.toLowerCase()
                      "
                    ></span>
                  </mat-select-trigger>
                  <mat-option [value]="null" show>Select Option</mat-option>
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of countryData" [value]="item">
                    <span
                      [class]="'flag flag-' + item.countryCode.toLowerCase()"
                    ></span>
                    {{ item.countryName + ' (+' + item.phoneCode + ')' }}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-form-field
                appearance="outline"                
                class="phone"
                style="width: 75%"
              >
                <mat-label                  
                  appearance="outline"
                >                 
                </mat-label>   
                <span matPrefix>{{ countrySelected }}</span>                        
                <input                  
                  formControlName="phone"
                  matInput             
                />                
              </mat-form-field>
          </div>         
          <div class="hr"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div
        *ngIf="Details.value.length < 5"
        class="add-fields"
        (click)="addDetails()"
      >
        <mat-icon class="icon">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
        <span class="text mat-button">
          {{ "ADD MORE Details"}}</span
        >
      </div>

addDetails() {        
    this.Details.push(this.createdetails());
  }
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly. When you select Afghanistan for example and click on the _Add more_ button, then it switches to Albania? Could you also show the code for `switchCountryForPhoneNumber`?

Comment: @RubenSzekér; for example If I select Afghanistan and click on add more then even in row 2 I can Afghanistan code instead of being empty. The problem is when user selects country in row1 I'm saving phonecode in countryselected. since country selected is already assigned on click addmore it is showingin matprefix.Please find the code for switchCountryForPhoneNumber in question

Comment: You could convert `countrySelected` to an array or map and stash all the phonecodes for each formGroup of your formArray by changing `switchCountryForPhoneNumber` to a method that pops sets the value depending on the formarray it is meant for. Even better would be to add it to your formArray. However, I know that working with formArrays is not that user friendly.